# Custom table view cell label hiding when scroll how to solve this?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

> "i am using custom cell class for showing time it show successfully but problem is that when i scroll down of table view and after that that timer label not showing.i have used this code but when i scroll down and again up of cell label of timer hide ,i am not getting how to solve this problem "

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=customCell;

}
return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  [cell startTimer:indexPath];
   }
```

//here mycell class code

```
  - (void) startTimer:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {


if (self.timer)

    [self.timer invalidate];


  currentIndexPath=indexPath;
   self.secondsLeft=10;


  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(calculateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

   [self.timer fire];
 }

   - (void)calculateTimer
  {

if (self.secondsLeft >0)
{

    self.secondsLeft --;
    self.timeLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",self.secondsLeft];
    self.showLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",self.secondsLeft];

}
if (self.secondsLeft==0)
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timeLbl.text=@"";
}

  }
   -(void)showTimer
    {
   self.timeLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.secondsLeft];
  NSLog(@"this is self second%d",self.secondsLeft);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it is not refreshing include these line in your method:-

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: No this not that means on scrolling timer label hiding

Comment: ok one question from where you are invoking this showTimer method??

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  [cell startTimer:indexPath];
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=customCell;

}
```

**Set ReuseIdentifier as nil.**

**Let me know if you have any problem.**

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
cell.textLabel.text=@"XYZ";
}
```

Comment: i used your code but same thing is happening,and thanks for that.

Comment: See my Updated answer. Try it & let me know.

Comment: i donot have to use cell.textLabel.text here i have to use it in my myCell class you can see my code upper.